# Sign in with Apple accessibility label

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, sign-in-with-apple

I’ve tried to implement custom Sign in with Apple button. Application supports L10n so label for the custom solution also has to be translated. Thought that I could simply get it from Apple like this:

```
ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .continue, style: .black).accessibilityLabel
```

But for all languages and settings it’s giving me always:

```
Continue with Apple
```

Is there something that I’m missing or this is a bug? Shouldn’t the accessibility label be also translated?